# OpenCL find maximum value and position in an array

Tags: max, opencl, mutex, atomic

I want to find the maximum value and its position in an image.
The kernel below gives me the correct maximum value but the position deviates and isn't always the same, even on images without the same gray value. I think this is caused by the if clause. Is there a way to synchronize the writing of the new max value (outValue) and the position of it (outIndex) or do I have to use two kernels, one to find the maximimum value and another to find its first appearance?

```
__kernel void findMaxValue(image2d_t __read_only in, __global uint* outIndex, __global uint* outValue) {
    const int2 origin = (int2)(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));
    const int imageWidth = get_global_size(0);
    const uint value = read_imageui(in, sampler, coord).x;

    atom_max(outValue, matches);
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    if (*outValue == matches) {
        const int index = origin.x + imageWidth * origin.y;
        *outIndex = index;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do research into "Reduction Kernels", as this is most definitely a classical example of a reduction kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I took a look on reduction kernels and changed my kernel according to it. The function above works now like expected.